# Performance/Code-readability of accessing object's field vs making a copy

Tags: c#, performance, coding-style

It was hard for me to explain precisely what I mean in the title, so I'll provide code samples right away.

Take a look at following C# code:

```
internal static async Task OnGroupGiveawayCreated(Giveaway giveaway) {
    if (giveaway == null) {
        return;
    }

    ulong creatorID = giveaway.CreatorID;
    if (creatorID == 0 || !await MySQL.UserExists(creatorID).ConfigureAwait(false)) {
        return;
    }

    // Date
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    if (today.Month == 9 && today.Day == 9) {
        await MySQL.InsertAchievement(40, creatorID).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await OnAchievementGot(creatorID).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

In above example I decided to make a copy of `giveaway.CreatorID` as a local variable, to omit a need of resolving the field of the object every time it's accessed. It's accessed a total of 4 times in worst case.

The above could be written also without doing that:

```
internal static async Task OnGroupGiveawayCreated(Giveaway giveaway) {
    if (giveaway == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (giveaway.CreatorID == 0 || !await MySQL.UserExists(giveaway.CreatorID).ConfigureAwait(false)) {
        return;
    }

    // Date
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    if (today.Month == 9 && today.Day == 9) {
        await MySQL.InsertAchievement(40, giveaway.CreatorID).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await OnAchievementGot(giveaway.CreatorID).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering which style is more preferred/recommended considering two factors - performance and readability.

1. [Performance] In second example, is compiler smart enough to notice that `giveaway` object is accessible only by one thread, therefore accessing `giveaway.CreatorID` does not have to be resolved on each call, but only on the first one? Is there any recommendation to use first or second approach performance-wise? I know that similar thing is being done e.g. in `for` loops, when we use e.g. `Length` property of string (when compiled to CIL, length of string is counted only once). If compiler wasn't smart enough to do that, it'd be wise to store it in a variable as well.
2. [Readability] Which way would you prefer to use? Does the choice depends upon the amount of times we access given field? I tend to make a copy of the field if it's accessed 2 or more times. Is it wrong? What about a really long "chains", such as `giveaway.CreatorID.Achievements.Count`?
3. Is there any other factor I should consider before making a decision whether to use first or second approach? Perhaps what I'm asking doesn't even matter because the answer should be obvious?

I'm sorry if what I'm asking is a complete nonsense and it doesn't matter at all, but from time to time I like to hear opinion of other programmers how they feel about given topic, so I can improve my code style in the future. For now I tend to make a copy of the field if it's accessed more than 1 time, but I don't know if it's required (from performance aspect), or recommended (from code readability one).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a temporary variable does not make sense as a micro-optimization, but it does make sense as a readability improvement.

Unless `Giveaway` is a `struct`, the compiler cannot possibly know that the object is accessed by only one thread. However, it does not need to know that, because it assumes that that's what is happening anyway: unless `CreatorID` is marked `volatile`, the compiler reserves the right to access it only once, and use a cached copy in subsequent invocations. That was a long way of saying "the compiler is smart enough to make a copy for you"

An important readability consequence of making a named copy is that it may save the reader from scrolling horizontally. This is a big deal, because horizontal scrolling slows down your readers. If you can give a variable a short name without going crazy, go for it. (`creatorID` is fine; `cid` is probably not descriptive enough).

Comment: Indeed `Giveaway` is a class, so compiler can't assume it's accessed only by one thread. Thanks for your thoughts, it helped me a lot to decide in keeping the habit of making such local copies for code readability.